# Android Google Account Manager Basic Login

Tags: android, accountmanager, google-signin

I'm developing app for android and I want it to have login through accounts that are saved on user's phone.

I have found this article: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/oauth-and-tasks-on-android

which was helpful but in this example I have to ask for permission for some kind of API (task, lattitude ...). All I need is just simple login to my service without need to redirect to some website and filling up password etc...

What would you suggest?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I depends on what you mean by 'login'. If you really want to use the Google account for authentication, you need to integrate OAuth or OpenID in your app and use Google as the identity provider (StackOverflow does this: you can login with your Google account) in your site/webapp. If you only need to get the user's GMail address, you can get it using the account manager. Since they need to authenticate at least once for it to show up in the list of accounts, you can be reasonably sure that it is really their address.

Comment: Yeah but oAuth does that what i don't want - to go out from app and then somewhere fill up login information that I already filled in my phone.

Comment: And I can't use email for authentification, somebody could change it on the way to server. I need some kind of token, which I can check on server too. Well i could use gmail API, but I don't know if everybody with google account has GMail.

Comment: They can't change if you use HTTPS. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: And of course there is this: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps

Comment: It's an app connected to server where user has account. They can login directly with name and password or via facebook or google. That's all, i just need to match users with their accounts. 

Well about HTTPS ... When somebody somehow gets my secret (which I use in API for my server) for now ... nothing really bad could happen they can just download some public lists of data. But with authentificating only with email they could access every account. So I would rather use some double check (on client and server).

Comment: Thanks, I tried that link before, but this opens browser window - this I don't want.

Comment: The idea is to embed a WebView in your app, so there is no app window. That is actually the idea of OAuth and similar protocols: the users only gives their credentials to services they trust already (GMail, Facebook), so seeing their login page is actually a good thing.

Comment: I get it, it works on the some principle like Facebook login. But that's what i'm trying to tell you: I want to do something else, take Accounts from AccountManager which are saved on phone and generate some token I can use for authentification. Why? Because it's easier for user to do just one click approval instead of filling up whole login form. 

Now I can get some token for particular api (Latitude, GMail, Tasks) but not some general token. 

I tried to find some app what does the same thing. Do you know some?

Thanks

Comment: Right. But there is no 'general' token, you need to generate one for your app and validate it accordingly. But then again, Andorid`s `AccountManager` probably won't support that. If you run on App Engine, you could get an OAuth token for your app. If you are running on some other infrastructure, you need to integrate OAuth and it may or may not work with `AcountManager` (it is not exactly well documented).

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. I will either do it with AccountManager and permissions for GMail or just OAuth...